# Subset a dataframe using start and stop points from another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, row, subset, sequence

I have a dataframe df with 3 columns id, first and last

```
id <- c(27,27,134,134)
first <- c(14,20,9,16)
last <- c(17,24,13,20)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,first,last))
df
```

Each row corresponds to a chunk of data from another dataframe that I want to keep. 
 first and last indicate the first and last frames of the relevant chunk
I want to use this to subset the other dataframe dat which is structured as below

```
dat_id <- c(rep(27, 30), rep(134,30))
dat_frame <- c(seq(1:30), seq(1:30))
dat_data <- c(sample(1:60))

dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(dat_id,dat_frame,dat_data))
dat
```

The only way I know to extract the relevant portion is with a for loop as below (this produces the expected output), but I expect this is a horribly inefficient way to do it. What's a better way?

```
#header row
new_df <- data.frame(id = numeric(), frame = numeric(), data = numeric())

#populate
for (i in (seq (1:nrow(df)))){
    new_df <- rbind(new_df, subset(dat, dat_id == df[i,"id"])[df[i,"first"]:df[i,"last"],])
}

new_df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` we can do a `left_join` on `dat` and `df` and select only those rows which lie in `between` `first` and `last` of their respective `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(dat, df, by = c("dat_id" = "id")) %>%
   filter(between(dat_frame, first, last)) %>%
   select(-first, -last)
```

Or using the same logic in base R

```
subset(merge(dat, df, by.x = "dat_id", by.y = "id", all.x = TRUE), 
             dat_frame >= first & dat_frame <= last)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you clarify a little the between(dat_data, first, last) part? I simplified above but my actual dataframe has 104 columns, how would this line change in that respect?

Comment: @Ronak, I think `filter(between(dat_frame, first, last))` is needed.

Comment: @AshaSato well, this first joins by `id` from both the dataframes and selects those rows where `dat_data` is between `first` and `last` of that `id`. It does not concern any other columns so those would be selected by default. Do you want to filter based on `dat_data` or `dat_frame` column as @Shree suggests ?

Comment: Ah yes now I understand. I was intending to filter based on dat_frame. It works when I use dat_frame.

Comment: @Shree Thanks..I think I had misunderstood the question earlier. I have edited the answer.

Comment: My fault, I think - I had a misleading typo in my question, I have fixed it now.

Comment: FYI your dplyr solution gives the right output, but the base R solution is doing something else.

Comment: @AshaSato yes, you are right. I had to include `all.x = TRUE` in `merge` to make it left join. I have corrected it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a complex join in sql. This avoids creating a large intermediate data frame based on joining only on id and then cutting it down.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("
  select dat.*
    from dat 
    join df on dat.dat_id = df.id and 
               dat.dat_frame between df.first and df.last
 ")
```

### Update

The example in the question changed and the solution has been simplified assuming the new example.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a non-equi join for this.  It would be more faster and efficient

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, newcol := dat_frame][df, on = .(dat_id = id,
    newcol >= first, newcol <=last)][, .(dat_id, dat_frame, dat_data)]
#     dat_id dat_frame dat_data
# 1:     27        14       26
# 2:     27        15       56
# 3:     27        16       30
# 4:     27        17       49
# 5:     27        20       23
# 6:     27        21       37
# 7:     27        22        7
# 8:     27        23       40
# 9:     27        24       12
#10:    134         9       57
#11:    134        10       35
#12:    134        11       31
#13:    134        12       53
#14:    134        13       38
#15:    134        16       15
#16:    134        17       14
#17:    134        18       33
#18:    134        19       54
#19:    134        20       43
```

---

Or another option is `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    mutate(newcol = dat_frame) %>%
    fuzzy_left_join(df, by = c("dat_id" = 'id', 'newcol' = 'first', 
      'newcol' = 'last'), match_fun = list(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)) %>% 
    na.omit %>%
    select(dat_id, dat_frame, dat_data)
#   dat_id dat_frame dat_data
#14     27        14       26
#15     27        15       56
#16     27        16       30
#17     27        17       49
#20     27        20       23
#21     27        21       37
#22     27        22        7
#23     27        23       40
#24     27        24       12
#39    134         9       57
#40    134        10       35
#41    134        11       31
#42    134        12       53
#43    134        13       38
#46    134        16       15
#47    134        17       14
#48    134        18       33
#49    134        19       54
#50    134        20       43
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
out <-  do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) do.call(rbind, 
  Map(function(u, v) subset(x,  dat_frame >= u & dat_frame <= v), 
     y$first, y$last)), split(dat, dat$dat_id), split(df, df$id)))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#   dat_id dat_frame dat_data
#1      27        14       26
#2      27        15       56
#3      27        16       30
#4      27        17       49
#5      27        20       23
#6      27        21       37
#7      27        22        7
#8      27        23       40
#9      27        24       12
#10    134         9       57
#11    134        10       35
#12    134        11       31
#13    134        12       53
#14    134        13       38
#15    134        16       15
#16    134        17       14
#17    134        18       33
#18    134        19       54
#19    134        20       43
```

NOTE: All the above solutions work

---

Also, note that the solution in the other post gives `Error`

```
left_join(dat, df, by = c("dat_id" = "id")) %>%
    filter(between(dat_frame, first, last)) %>%
    select(-first, -last)
#Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=120].
```

NOTE: That the accepted answer is wrong and it is giving error.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't the expected output (I think I was unclear formulating the question). The other solution works as intended when I replace dat_data with dat_frame.

Comment: I had a typo in my original post in the creation of the first dataframe, it works now