# How to subset windows in a dataframe using start- and end-values from another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, subset, purrr

I have a dataframe of timeseries data, `df1`, that I need to extract a number of 'windows' from in R. The start- and end-points for the windows I need are in two columns of a separate dataframe, `df2`. The values for the start- and end-points correspond to the rownumbers of the windows required.

In the example below I am part of the way to a solution but currently only the first window is extracted. How do I amend this example to extract all four windows? Could this be a case for *purrr*?

```
library(tidyverse)

# dataframe of data to subset
df1 <- tibble(my_values = rnorm(100))

# dataframe of windows (i.e. row number IDs) to extract from data
df2 <-tibble::tribble(
        ~window_start, ~window_end,
                   3L,         10L,
                  21L,         25L,
                  52L,         63L,
                  78L,         90L
        )

# extracted data
df3 <- df1 %>% 
  slice(df2$window_start : df2$window_end)
```

(NB. I am aware there is a similar question here - [Subset a dataframe using start and stop points from another dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450769/subset-a-dataframe-using-start-and-stop-points-from-another-dataframe) - but my actual data is very large and I am curious whether a non-merge-based solution will be quicker.)

Comment: What are the dimensions of your actual data?

Comment: It will vary, but in the region of >3 million rows * 75 cols for the timeseries dataframe, and 10,000 rows for the windows dataframe.

Comment: To avoid the `map` loops, you can try `data.table::inrange`; `x[data.table::inrange(x, d[ , "start"], d[ , "end"])]`, where "x" is the vector of values to be filtered, and "d" a data frame with start and end columns of intervals. For a `base` alternative, see `findInterval`, e.g. `brk = c(t(as.matrix(d)))`; `x[findInterval(x, brk) %% 2 == 1 & findInterval(x, brk, left.open = TRUE) %% 2 == 1]` (if the intervals are non-overlapping)

Comment: If your not specifically looking for a (potentially slow) tidyverse solution, check [Efficient way to filter one data frame by ranges in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454565/efficient-way-to-filter-one-data-frame-by-ranges-in-another). (I tried the above on `x = 1:15`; `d = data.frame(start = c(2, 7, 12), end = c(4, 10, 15))`. You haven't clarified if boundaries are open or closed,, but see `incbounds` argument in `inrange`, and the various boundary arguments in `findInterval`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe try this approach with `purrr::map2`

```r
# dataframe of data to subset
df1 <- tibble(my_values = rnorm(100, mean = 45, sd = 30) %>% abs())

# dataframe of windows (i.e. row number IDs) to extract from data
df2 <-tibble::tribble(
  ~window_start, ~window_end,
  3L,         10L,
  21L,         25L,
  52L,         63L,
  78L,         90L
)

subset_thats_in <- function(mini, maxi){
  df1 %>% 
    filter(between(my_values, mini, maxi))
}

purrr::map2(df2$window_start, 
            df2$window_end, 
            subset_thats_in)
```

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  my_values
      <dbl>
1      6.47
2      8.69
3      7.73
4      7.35

[[2]]
# A tibble: 12 × 1
   my_values
       <dbl>
 1      24.2
 2      22.9
 3      22.4
 4      24.4
 5      22.6
 6      21.7
 7      23.2
 8      21.3
 9      23.3
10      21.1
11      23.5
12      22.6

[[3]]
# A tibble: 10 × 1
   my_values
       <dbl>
 1      54.0
 2      61.4
 3      62.5
 4      60.8
 5      60.5
 6      55.5
 7      61.4
 8      59.0
 9      57.9
10      53.3

[[4]]
# A tibble: 6 × 1
  my_values
      <dbl>
1      87.8
2      79.1
3      80.5
4      82.7
5      85.2
6      80.6
```

Answer (score 2):

`purrr` is quite memory efficient for such data transformations. However, a list of length 10000 may still be beefy if data is to be copied.

```
x = vector(mode = "list", 10000L)

x = purrr::transpose(df2) |> lapply(function(x) df1[x[1]:x[2],])
```

`as.numeric` on a transposed list gets the range, which can be used to subset df1.
For larger sets, it might be useful to try a vectorized approach. Below is a base R option, tweak `SIMPLIFY = TRUE` to reduce it to a vector, in case you are working with a single column.

```
f = Vectorize(\(x, y) df1[seq.int(x, y),], SIMPLIFY = F)
f(df2[[1]], df2[[2]])
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map2`

```r
library(tidyverse)

map2(df2[[1]], df2[[2]], ~ df1[.x:.y, ])
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 8 × 1
#>   my_values
#>       <dbl>
#> 1   1.33   
#> 2   1.27   
#> 3   0.415  
#> 4  -1.54   
#> 5  -0.929  
#> 6  -0.295  
#> 7  -0.00577
#> 8   2.40   
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 5 × 1
#>   my_values
#>       <dbl>
#> 1   -0.224 
#> 2    0.377 
#> 3    0.133 
#> 4    0.804 
#> 5   -0.0571
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 12 × 1
#>    my_values
#>        <dbl>
#>  1   -0.377 
#>  2    2.44  
#>  3   -0.795 
#>  4   -0.0549
#>  5    0.250 
#>  6    0.618 
#>  7   -0.173 
#>  8   -2.22  
#>  9   -1.26  
#> 10    0.359 
#> 11   -0.0110
#> 12   -0.941 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # A tibble: 13 × 1
#>    my_values
#>        <dbl>
#>  1    -0.118
#>  2    -0.912
#>  3    -1.44 
#>  4    -0.797
#>  5     1.25 
#>  6     0.772
#>  7    -0.220
#>  8    -0.425
#>  9    -0.419
#> 10     0.997
#> 11    -0.276
#> 12     1.26 
#> 13     0.647
```

Or dplyr creatively.

```
df2 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  transmute(windows = list(c_across(starts_with("window")) %>% {df1[.[[1]]:.[[2]], ]}))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#> # Rowwise: 
#>   windows          
#>   <list>           
#> 1 <tibble [8 × 1]> 
#> 2 <tibble [5 × 1]> 
#> 3 <tibble [12 × 1]>
#> 4 <tibble [13 × 1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

data:

```
set.seed(0)

# dataframe of data to subset
df1 <- tibble(my_values = rnorm(100))

# dataframe of windows (i.e. row number IDs) to extract from data
df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~window_start, ~window_end,
  3L, 10L,
  21L, 25L,
  52L, 63L,
  78L, 90L
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `mapply`:

```
df1[unlist(mapply(function(x,y) x:y, df2$window_start, df2$window_end)),]

# A tibble: 38 x 1
   my_values
       <dbl>
 1     0.671
 2    -0.617
 3    -0.354
 4     2.76 
 5     0.382
 6    -0.488
 7     0.889
 8    -1.32 
 9     0.328
10     0.779
# ... with 28 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple base R solution would be using the `sequence` function to generate all the row indices you need to subset the dataframe. The first argument of `sequence` specifies the length of the sequence to be generated each starting from a number given in the second argument. This should be very efficient since the only thing the function does is creating a sequence of integers.

```
df1[sequence(df2$window_end - df2$window_start + 1L, df2$window_start), ]
```

Output

```
> set.seed(1234L)
> df1 <- tibble(my_values = rnorm(100))
> df1[sequence(df2$window_end - df2$window_start + 1L, df2$window_start), ]
# A tibble: 38 x 1
   my_values
       <dbl>
 1     1.08 
 2    -2.35 
 3     0.429
 4     0.506
 5    -0.575
 6    -0.547
 7    -0.564
 8    -0.890
 9     0.134
10    -0.491
# ... with 28 more rows
```

You can also get minor performance improvement by using `data.table:::vecseq`. The code is very similar to the above:

```
df1[data.table:::vecseq(df2$window_start, df2$window_end - df2$window_start + 1L, NULL), ]
```

Further reading:
[data.table efficient recycling V2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65024489/10802499)